# How to read multidimensional dataframe in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, multidimensional-array, xml-parsing

I designed a scraping tool in Beautiful soup which scrapes XML data and stores it in a dataframe in Pandas. However, in a column ('aFname'), I have multiple entries and Python stored it as a dtype objects. It looks something like:

```
IN: df['aFname']

OUT:

0                 [[[], []], [[], []], [[], []], [[], []]]

1                                     [[[], []], [[], []]]
```

I have tried:

```
IN: df['aFname'][[0]].values

OUT:

array([<Element '{http://arxiv.org/OAI/arXiv/}authors' at 0x8ca9da0>], dtype=object)
```

There are author names in the xml file, can anyone help me by telling me how to access these columns?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you show us an example for column 'aFname' when 'Authors' is the relevant column? Or is this a typo?

Comment: The technical column name is aFname but I referred it as Authors for simplicity